# Mac OS X: If there's a header needed when compile linux kernel, but os x doesn't have, where should I put it to?

Tags: c, macos, linux-kernel

Here's the situation:
I am using a mac to compile Linux kernel for an arm board, some how this happened:

```
arch/arm/vdso/vdsomunge.c:48:10: fatal error: 'byteswap.h' file not found
```

I googled and find out that mac doesn't have a 'byteswap.h', so I download a 'byteswap.h' version based on 'OSByteOrder.h' write by others, but I don't know where to put that header.

Any one can help?

Comment: Don't grab headers copied from random locations on the Internet, there's a high probability to get the version and/or platform wrong, with bizarre consequences for your build.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself: put it in /usr/include, and problem solved.

Comment: Put it on /usr/local/include, otherwise it may be deleted when you do a system update.